systemd-networkd is loading config but not applying it
I have two network interfaces, eno1 and eth0. I would like both to use DHCP to get an IP address. I would like eno1 to be used as a default route for everything. The only time I want to use eth0 is when specifying interface in a curl command.
I have created two configuration files:
root:/etc/systemd/network$ ls -la
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Oct 20 10:50 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 Oct 20 10:51 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   59 Oct 20 09:54 10-eno1.network
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   59 Oct 20 10:41 20-eth0.network

root:/etc/systemd/network$ cat 10-eno1.network
[Match]
Name=eno1

[Network]
DHCP=yes

[Route]
Metric=100

root:/etc/systemd/network$ cat 20-eth0.network
[Match]
Name=eth0

[Network]
DHCP=yes

[Route]
Metric=4000

I have tried restarting and playing around with the metrics, however, they don't seem to take effect.
root:/etc/systemd/network$ systemctl status systemd-networkd
● systemd-networkd.service - Network Configuration
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/systemd-networkd.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sun 2024-10-20 10:51:59 UTC; 12min ago
TriggeredBy: ● systemd-networkd.socket
       Docs: man:systemd-networkd.service(8)
             man:org.freedesktop.network1(5)
   Main PID: 24821 (systemd-network)
     Status: "Processing requests..."
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 76956)
   FD Store: 0 (limit: 512)
     Memory: 1.7M (peak: 2.1M)
        CPU: 32ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/systemd-networkd.service
             └─24821 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-networkd

Oct 20 10:51:59 systemd-networkd[24821]: eth0: Link UP
Oct 20 10:51:59 systemd-networkd[24821]: eth0: Gained carrier
Oct 20 10:51:59 systemd-networkd[24821]: eno1: Gained IPv6LL
Oct 20 10:51:59 systemd-networkd[24821]: eth0: Gained IPv6LL
Oct 20 10:51:59 systemd-networkd[24821]: Enumeration completed
Oct 20 10:51:59 systemd[1]: Started systemd-networkd.service - Network Configuration.
Oct 20 10:51:59 systemd-networkd[24821]: eno1: Configuring with /etc/systemd/network/10-eno1.network.
Oct 20 10:51:59 systemd-networkd[24821]: eth0: Configuring with /etc/systemd/network/20-eth0.network.
Oct 20 10:51:59 systemd-networkd[24821]: eno1: DHCPv4 address 192.168.0.2/24, gateway 192.168.0.1 acquired from 192.168.0.1
Oct 20 10:51:59 systemd-networkd[24821]: eth0: DHCPv4 address 192.168.0.99/24, gateway 192.168.0.1 acquired from 192.168.0.1

root:/etc/systemd/network$ ip route show
default via 192.168.0.1 dev eno1 proto dhcp src 192.168.0.2 metric 1024
default via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp src 192.168.0.99 metric 1024
128.138.140.44 via 192.168.0.1 dev eno1 proto dhcp src 192.168.0.2 metric 1024
128.138.140.44 via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp src 192.168.0.99 metric 1024
192.168.0.0/24 dev eno1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.2 metric 1024
192.168.0.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.99 metric 1024
192.168.0.1 dev eno1 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.0.2 metric 1024
192.168.0.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.0.99 metric 1024


I have managed to delete the default route using ip route del default dev eth0 and add it with a metric 4000 using sudo ip route add default via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0 metric 4000. Everything works as expected. Why can't this just be loaded from config?

@GAD3R systemd-resolved is running without any issues. It's for resolving DNS, why would it play a role here?

When using DHCP it looks like you have to specify a metric differently.
From the DHCPv4 section of man
systemd.network
we have

UseRoutes= 
When true (the default), the static routes will be requested from the DHCP server and added to the routing table with a metric of 1024


RouteMetric= 
Set the routing metric for routes specified by the DHCP server

So you need to add
[DHCPv4]
RouteMetric=4000

